# Firefox stuck in 6.0 and not updating. Apt-get says that its latest version

Tags: apt, updates, firefox, update-manager

I'm having trouble updating Firefox, it does not update from the terminal and doesn't show up in the update manager. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.

If I run `apt-get install firefox` it claims that the latest version is already installed and if I run `firefox -v` I get that Mozilla Firefox is version 6.0.2.

How can I solve this problem?

I don't want to manually download and upgrade firefox with archives and move and deleting folders every time a new version I released.

**Update**:

The output of `sudo apt-get update` is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5714487/).

Comment: What's your Ubuntu version? Did you run `apt-get update` before `apt-get install firefox`?

Comment: Hi, yes I did run apt-get update first and I have version 12.04

Comment: Please, upload the output of `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. You can upload it in paste.ubuntu.com and link it here.

Comment: No problemo: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5714487/

Comment: @Axel: What's the output of `which firefox` and `cat "$(which firefox)"`? Perhaps you installed a second copy of Firefox from outside the package manager, which is taking precedence.

Comment: If you do `apt-cache policy firefox` what is the result?

Comment: Why are there maverick lines in your source list?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the output of your `sudo apt-get update` command, it seems like you have a broken `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. To fix this, open Software sources by typing "software sources" in your dash and then check if there is a tick on the following:

- Canonical-supported free and  open-source software (main)
- Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)
- Software restricted by  copyright or legal issues (multiverse)

and the download takes place from the server nearest to you("Main Server" is fine for the moment but it may be busy at times).

And then open a terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and type the following:

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install firefox
```

You should have the latest version of firefox now.

Comment: There's a 404 but that wouldn't stop it working (it's a warning not an error). The rest of the sources look legit.

Comment: @Oli: He has `maverick` in his `/etc/apt/sources.list`!

Comment: I see that and I agree it's weird but technically irrelevant here because there's also `precise-security/main i386 Packages` which [contains the latest version of `firefox`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=firefox&searchon=names&section=all). Neither the maverick lines (nor the 404 warnings) could stop apt picking the latest version of Firefox.